# How to create unique array of object from API response in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have below API response need to construct unique array of object based on ID.

```
const response = [{id: "ABC", value: 120, day: "MON"},{id: "ABC", value: 120, day: "TUE"},{id: "ABC", value: 120, day: "WED"},{id: "ABC", value: 120, day: "THU"},{id: "ABC", value: 120, day: "FRI"},
{id: "XYZ", value: 120, day: "TUE"},{id: "XYZ", value: 140, day: "WED"},{id: "XYZ", value: 160, day: "FRI"},{id: "SUV", value: 120, day: "MON"},{id: "SUV", value: 140, day: "TUE"}];
```

I want unique array of object like below

```
obj = [{ItemID: "ABC", MON: 120, TUE: 120, WED: 120, THU: 120, FRI: 120 }, {ItemID: "XYZ", TUE: 120, WED: 140, FRI: 160 }, {ItemID: "SUV", MON: 120, TUE: 140} ];
```

I tried the below method

```
let obj = {ItemID: ""};
let arr = [];
response.forEach(el => {
let day = el.day;
  obj.ItemID = el.id;
  obj[day] = el.value
}
)

arr.push(obj);

console.log(arr)
```

Using above code i am always getting below array of object. I am not able append another object when id is not matched

```
obj = [{ItemID: "ABC", MON: 120, TUE: 120, WED: 120, THU: 120, FRI: 120 }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) along with [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values).

```js
const response = [{id: "ABC", value: 120, day: "MON"},{id: "ABC", value: 120, day: "TUE"},{id: "ABC", value: 120, day: "WED"},{id: "ABC", value: 120, day: "THU"},{id: "ABC", value: 120, day: "FRI"},
{id: "XYZ", value: 120, day: "TUE"},{id: "XYZ", value: 140, day: "WED"},{id: "XYZ", value: 160, day: "FRI"},{id: "SUV", value: 120, day: "MON"},{id: "SUV", value: 140, day: "TUE"}];

const formatResponse = (data) => {
  const finalRes = data.reduce((res, {id, value, day}) => {
      res[id] = {
        ItemID: id,
        ...res[id],
        [day]: value
      }   
    return res;
  },{});

  return Object.values(finalRes)
}

console.log(formatResponse(response))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Using `Array.forEach` also it can be achieved but then `reduce` makes more informative when we look at the method, that we are doing some kind of processing and accumulating the provided data based on id.

```js
const response = [{id: "ABC", value: 120, day: "MON"},{id: "ABC", value: 120, day: "TUE"},{id: "ABC", value: 120, day: "WED"},{id: "ABC", value: 120, day: "THU"},{id: "ABC", value: 120, day: "FRI"},
{id: "XYZ", value: 120, day: "TUE"},{id: "XYZ", value: 140, day: "WED"},{id: "XYZ", value: 160, day: "FRI"},{id: "SUV", value: 120, day: "MON"},{id: "SUV", value: 140, day: "TUE"}];

const processResponse = (data) => {
  const finalRes = {};
  data.forEach(({id, value, day}) => {
    finalRes[id] = {
      ItemID: id,
      ...finalRes[id],
      [day]: value
    }
  });

  return Object.values(finalRes)
}

console.log(processResponse(response));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing forEach way. It's solve my one problem. I need to format the day before pushing into using moment which is not happening due to reduce method. But it's work with forEach

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to accumulate the objects in an array and `Array.prototype.find` to search for the existing object with the particular `ItemID` in the array.

If found modify the object with the new data else add a fresh new object:

```js
const response = [{id: "ABC", value: 120, day: "MON"},{id: "ABC", value: 120, day: "TUE"},{id: "ABC", value: 120, day: "WED"},{id: "ABC", value: 120, day: "THU"},{id: "ABC", value: 120, day: "FRI"},
{id: "XYZ", value: 120, day: "TUE"},{id: "XYZ", value: 140, day: "WED"},{id: "XYZ", value: 160, day: "FRI"},{id: "SUV", value: 120, day: "MON"},{id: "SUV", value: 140, day: "TUE"}];

const processObject = (res) => {
  return res.reduce((acc, o) => {
    let day = acc.find(d => d.ItemID === o.id);
    if (day) {
      day[o.day] = o.value;
    } else {
      acc.push({
        ItemID: o.id,
        [o.day]: o.value
      });
    }
    return acc;
  }, [])
}
console.log(processObject(response));
```

In your code you are always overriding the same object, you should create a new object when the `ItemID` has changed. if it is the same `ItemID` you should search for it and modify the result or create a new one and push into the final array.

Comment: Can we achieve through forEach only ?